# Switching between two texlive distributions

Tags: texlive

I have installed (windows 10) two texlive distributions (2018-2021) . How to switch easly and fastly between them.

Comment: Change the system's `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks but I search for a faster way

Comment: Even faster? Well, changing the system's path may be written into some batch or powershell script that toggles paths. I don't know of anything faster, so maybe someone else can chime in.